"How to use messages.Report with Pyrogram RAW API? Getting 'can't
from pyrogram.raw.functions.messages import Report


from pyrogram.raw.functions.channels import GetChannels
from pyrogram.raw.types import InputPeerChannel, InputReportReasonSpam
from pyrogram.raw import functions, types

@app.on_message(filters.command('start') & filters.private)
async def start_bot(cleint, mesage):
    print('start command')
    await mesage.reply_text('hello welcome to my bot', reply_markup=buttons.start())

    chat = await app.get_chat('example')
    peer = await app.resolve_peer(chat.id)
    result = await app.invoke(GetChannels(id=[peer])) 


    for channel in result.chats:
        channel_id =channel.id
        access_hash =channel.access_hash

    peer = InputPeerChannel(channel_id=channel_id, access_hash=access_hash)
    try:
        async with Client(":memory:",session_string='session strig ') as bot:

            result = await bot.invoke(
                functions.messages.Report(
                    peer = peer,
                    id=[8409],
                    reason = InputReportReasonSpam(),
                    message='hi'
                )
            )
            print(result)
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)

I also used the option instead of the reason, but it didn't work
Has anyone had this problem before?
If you have a solution, give an example.
Thank youReport.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reason'‍‍‍‍‍
